# Would Canada have to leave the Commonwealth to have a president?

Tags: united-kingdom, president, canada, commonwealth

If Canada wanted to have a president, would that mean it would have to leave the Commonwealth?

Comment: This question is currently rather short.  In a comment on the answer you imply that the reason for this belief had something to do with Ireland.  You might flesh that out more to build up the question.

Comment: Do you mean the Commonwealth of Nations or a Commonwealth Realm? Canada is both, but the latter is stricter: it means they recognize HM Queen Elizabeth II as their head of state (but they could probably still elect a President if they wanted to)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope. India and Pakistan are members of the Commonwealth, and they both have presidents.

Ireland left the Commonwealth when it became a republic before the London Declaration that allowed countries in the Commonwealth to have a different head of state.

Comment: but Ireland has a president and no longer a commonwealth country (?)

Comment: @Thedude: Yes, Ireland left when it became a republic before the London Declaration that allowed countries in the Commonwealth to have a different head of state.

Comment: You could add that comment to the answer, as it is a very important part of it.

Answer (score -2):

In short, no. Zimbabwe has been a republic since independence and remained a member of the commonwealth

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Having a president and being a republic are not the same thing.